# Adding key listener to JPopupMenu from a JTextPane works, but not from JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, popup, jtextarea

Please see my sample code.

```
JPopupMenu popUp = new JPopupMenu();
popUp.add(new JMenuItem("sample1"));
popUp.add(new JMenuItem("sample2"));

popUp.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("yy");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("yy");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("yy");
    }
});
popUp.setVisible(true);
popUp.show(textPane, 0, 0);
popUp.requestFocus();
```

The same code doesn't work when using a `JTextArea` as parent component for the pop-up.
My logic is to add focus on pop-up and then use it's key pressed even to re-populate the pop-up.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do. You should not need to add a KeyListener to a popup. A popup menu will support moving from item to item already.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Bringing Up a Popup Menu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) for more information and examples.

> use it's key pressed even to re-populate the pop-up.

You should be setting the items of the popup before the popup is made visible.

> Adding key listener to JPopupMenu from a JTextPane works, but not from JTextArea

Then post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the working code and the non-working code. If we understand what you are attempting to do, then we might be able to provide a better alternative for both components.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me. Can you elaborate on the re-population of the pop-up logic?

```
 JPopupMenu popUp = new JPopupMenu();
    popUp.add(new JMenuItem("sample1"));
    popUp.add(new JMenuItem("sample2"));

    popUp.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("yy");
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("yy");
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("yy");
        }
    });

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JTextArea txtArea = new JTextArea();
    f.add(txtArea);
    f.setSize(300, 150);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
    popUp.setVisible(true);
    popUp.show(txtArea, 0, 0);
    popUp.requestFocus();
```